# Plotly interactive bar chart doesn't remove the previous trace before displaying new trace

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am trying to create an interactive *plotly* bar chart.

```
select_feat = widgets.Dropdown(options=['overall_rating', 'potential'], description='Feature')

fig_1 = go.FigureWidget()

def response_1(feature):
    x = player_info.groupby(['player_name'])[feature].mean().nlargest(5)
    val = list(x.values)
    lab = list(x.index.values)
    fig_1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=lab, y=val))
    fig_1.update_layout(title='Top five playes by average')

VBox((fig_1, interactive(response_1, feature=select_feat)))
```

When I executed the code, [I got this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1y3D.png) for overall_rating. When chose option potential, [I got this plot which has trace zero and one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKZtG.png). Messi, Ronaldo, and Iniesta are at the top of both overall_rating and potential. So it is showing two bars for them.
So what can I do to that only selected feature related trace is shown.

I am using plotly offline in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing add_trace with update_traces and adding (data=[{'type':'bar'}] in FigureWidget(), I resolved the issue.